# R Shiny Apps - How to stop shell commands which can delete OS files from the eval expression

Tags: r, security, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

So, I have found that we can run shell commands which can delete important files from the input text field which performs the eval operation. I am interested in finding an alternative way to run eval expression without executing the shell commands. Below is a reproducible example.

Directory Structure

```
|-- app.R
|-- Imp_file.txt
```

app.R

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("text","Input"),
  actionButton("Run", "Execute")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$Run,{
    text = input$text
    eval(parse(text = text))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

After running the R Shiny application, if I enter a shell command like

```
shell("del Imp_File.txt")
```

in the the Input text field. This will actually delete the file. Is there a way to avoid shell commands in the input text field so it can ignore shell commands but still evaluate expression.

Thanks for your time and suggestions.

Comment: You would need to sanitize `input$text` before `eval`ing it. Depending on what kind of actions you want to allow, this may be a tricky task, as there are a myriad of ways how to circumvent this sanitizer unless you are very strict on what you want to allow, in which case the `eval` approach may anyways not be the best. Long story short, you can use `eval` for great flexibility, but you open a wide door to malicious content.

Comment: Hence, it is really **feature** and not a **bug**